# What is complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, complexity-theory

May you solve this:
What is **complexity** of this algorithm?

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   i*=m;
```

Comment: Yes, But I don't know why I'm stuck in this.

Comment: What complexity do you think it has? And why?

Comment: Or can you tell me a complexity you do not think it has and why?

Comment: i*=m is my problem and I don't know how it can change the complexity.

Comment: Why do you think it changes the complexity?

Comment: Oh, forget everything I said

Comment: T(n). when your input (n) growth, your run time how changes.

Comment: I just realized that it was far from trivial. Have not finished my morning coffee :D

Comment: But where did you find this? Is it an actual problem or something you just made up on your own?

Comment: It's a home work of my university.

Comment: Well, thing is, if m=1, then it's O(n), and if m=n, then it's O(1)

Comment: yeh. i solved this problem like your way. but some my friends said another way. and this why i stuck in.

Comment: and in your way. we need find average complexity??

Comment: I don't know. It completely depends on how the question is phrased.

Comment: (n + 1)/2 and the result (final result) can be O(n)

Comment: So however thanks for answering.

Comment: something like `log(n)`

Comment: @MBo The base is irrelevant

Comment: @Mbo can you say your solutions. something like picture or anything that i can see your solutions way?

Comment: @klutt some my friends said this result. so i don't think it was accidently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider sequence of `i` at every step:

```
 0    =>  0
 1    =>  m
 m+1  =>  m^2+m   
 m^2+m+1 => m^3+m^2+m
 m^3+m^2+m+1 => m^4+m^3+m^2+m
```

So we can see polynom for `m`, and it is known that

```
m^k+m^(k-1)+...+1 = m^(k+1)/(m-1)    //might be checked with multiplication by (m-1)
```

This expression should reach n, so rough estimation is

```
 m^k~n
 k = log(n) base m   //number of steps
```

We can ignore logarithm base, so number of steps and number of operations (there is constant number of operations per loop step) is estimated as `O(log(n))`